# Find a child node and get the value of it using a variable. Windows phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, nodes

So i am able to select all the results under a certain node, but I have the following XML

```
<ArrayOfStop>
 <Stop>
   <StopName>Rajdutt Restaurant</StopName>
   <route_stop />
   <route_stop_stop />
   <route_stop_timetable_stop />
   <stopId>6400</stopId>
 </Stop>
 <Stop>
   <StopName>Cysleys Farm (by request only)</StopName>
   <route_stop />
   <route_stop_stop />
   <route_stop_timetable_stop />
   <stopId>6401</stopId>
 </Stop>
<ArrayOfStop>
```

If i want to select stopId if the stopname was Cysleys Farm (by request only) how would one go about it?

I have the following code:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("People.xml");

var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("ArrayOfStop")
           select new Person
           { 
             StopName = (string)query.Element("StopName") 
           };

listBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

EDIT:

```
var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("ArrayOfStop") 
  where query.Element("StopName").Value == "Cysleys Farm (by request only)" 
  select query.Element("StopId").Value; 

select new Person
{
   FirstName = (string)query.Element("StopName"),
   //LastName = (string)query.Element("Long"),
   //Age = (int)query.Element("age")
};

listBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

[image: Visual Studio Editor]

EDIT 2

Do the items need to be going into a list box? As i need the value in a string format to use on a url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var doc =
            XDocument.Parse(
                "<ArrayOfStop><Stop><StopName>Rajdutt Restaurant</StopName><route_stop /><route_stop_stop /><route_stop_timetable_stop /><stopId>6400</stopId></Stop><Stop><StopName>Cysleys Farm (by request only)</StopName><route_stop /><route_stop_stop /><route_stop_timetable_stop /><stopId>6401</stopId></Stop></ArrayOfStop>");

        var list = (from item in doc.Descendants("Stop")
                    where (string) item.Element("StopName") == "Cysleys Farm (by request only)"
                    select (string)item.Element("stopId")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks if i put that in like shown above, then there are errors and i can't put that result into a list box.

Comment: Have put a image in, the erros are in order :
Error 4 ; expected 

Error 1 Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
  
Error 3 The name 'query' does not exist in the current context

Error 2 The name 'select' does not exist in the current contet

Comment: wow. Do you understand anything from that code you have on your file, about LINQ? You have to remove whole `select ...` part ...

Comment: Hi, no I don't, i have removed that line, now just says NullReferenceException even though there is a stop. on the where part

Comment: OK, another update made. I've tested it with your sample data and it returned proper results.

Comment: Cool thanks, is there a way to modify if to parse the file, as i have over 40,000 lines i need to parse to get the data from???

Comment: No, you don't. Your `Document.Load()` is OK as well.

Comment: Ok, great, forgot to put down, does the result have to be used as a list format? I need the result in a string format, if possible.

Comment: Replace `.ToList()` with `.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

This will get you a single node that has a matching value. If you expect more than one node will have a matching value and only want the first one, then use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault`.

```
string search = "Cysleys Farm (by request only)";
var query = doc.Root.Elements()
            .SingleOrDefault( x => x.Element( "StopName" ).Value == search );

if (query != null)
{
    // if the query is not null, then this will be 
    // a single node with a root of <Stop>
    string id = query.Element( "stopId" ).Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("People.xml");

// Select the 'StopId' node whose StopName is 'Cysleys Farm (by request only)'
XmlNode stopIdNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ArrayOfStop/Stop[StopName='Cysleys Farm (by request only)']/stopId");

string stopId = stopIdNode.InnerText;
```

If there are multiple nodes with the same StopName, then you can store them in a list:

```
List<string> stopIdList = new List<string>();

foreach (XmlNode stopIdNode 
         in xmlDoc.SelectNodes
         ("/ArrayOfStop/Stop[StopName='Cysleys Farm (by request only)']/stopId"))
{
    stopIdList.Add(stopIdNode.InnerText);
}
```